# Command Line Parameters not working properly

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get this script working properly. When I'm executing this bash-script with:

```
./parameters.sh -name="Jonathan" -id="1"
```

I'm getting the output: -id 1

I'm expecting an output like: Jonathan 1

```
#!/bin/bash

global=$*

function parameters() {
    for arguments in $global; do
        name=$(echo "$arguments" | cut -f1 -d=)
        value=$(echo "$arguments" | cut -f2 -d=)
        case "$name" in
            -name)    name=$value;;
            -id)      id=$value;;
            *)        echo "This parameter is not reconized."
        esac
    done

    echo "$name"
    echo "$id"
}

parameters
```

What do I have to change after the pipe inside the cut to make it working?

```
name=$(echo "$arguments" | cut -f1 -d=)
value=$(echo "$arguments" | cut -f2 -d=)
```

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't try to use the name variable for multiple things...

Comment: Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#function_foo.28.29

Comment: Hi Shawn, you were right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest with `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

global=$*

parameters() {
    for arguments in $global; do
        [[ "$arguments" =~ (.*)=(.*) ]]
        option="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        value="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"

        case "$option" in
            -name)    name="$value";;
            -id)      id="$value";;
            *)        echo "This parameter is not reconized."
        esac
    done

    echo "$name"
    echo "$id"
}

parameters
```

Comment: Thank you. After I also adjusted the "name" variable (as recommended by Shawn) it worked. I also tried your answer and it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Instead of using regular expression, this is simpler : `IFS== read option value <<< "$arguments"`

Comment: Take a look at ```getopt``` it is designed for (from DESCRIPTION): "getopt is used to break up (parse) options in command lines for easy parsing by shell procedures, and to check for valid options."